# Ajax is not working going to 404 in Magento 2.4.2 Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, ajax, 404

I am creating module for frontend and backend and want to run ajax with in the modules.
My ajax is perfectly working on frontend but it doesn't work on admin side.

My Ajax URL is http://127.0.0.1/mag/createmenubackend/create/ajax/?isAjax=true which goes to 404.

The result but AJAX goes to 404 Not Found. What's the issue i didn't get this.Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed "admin" in you'r URL before createmenubackend.

> url: 'http://hl.local/admin/createmenubackend/create/ajax/'+'?isAjax=true'

Actually, you have to call Direct URL function in JS otherwise you have to change URL again and again on different platforms like local, stage & Production like EX. below:

> define([
> 'mage/url' ], function (urlBuilder) {
> var customLink =
> urlBuilder.build('customer/account/login');
> console.log(customLink);
> });

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have done that actually my url is diffrent and you are right i have move my js part in phtml file with <?php echo $block->getUrl('name_of_url'); ?> and it worked. Will you please tell me how to save that data in database in my custom table i have created table in my database.

Comment: There are multiple links, you can refer below one or just google it simply:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303958/ajax-in-magento2-how-to-add-information-from-form-in-database

Comment: Thanks for the link @Ankit I have done that and it worked will you please tell me how to insert  image data in database in Magento 2.