# I have created a modal pop up form in product detail page and need to submit data in database. Please share the links for it

Tags: database, modal-popup, frontend-model, submit-form

I have performed admin crud operation and now I need to submit data from the frontend through the website. Kindly share the reference for the same. I need to know how it will distinguish that in which table it will store data.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303958/ajax-in-magento2-how-to-add-information-from-form-in-database

Comment: How form gets to know in which table it will save the data? I have two table in one module.

Comment: you can do that on your controller, your tables associated with Model, right . so you can create a new object for the mode land set your data , then save